# How can I change while to do-while in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

How can I change while to do-while in Java?

```
int numPlayers=0;
        while (menu < 1 || menu >3 ){
            System.out.println("Welcome to Snakes & Ladders");
            System.out.println("1. 2 Player" );
            System.out.println("2. 3 Player");
            System.out.println("3. Exit");
            System.out.print("Choice: ");
            menu = scan.nextInt();
        }
        if(menu==1) {
            numPlayers=2;
        }
        else if(menu==2) {
            numPlayers=3;
        }
        else if(menu==3){
            break;
        }
```

Comment: https://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/do-while-loop-in-java-with-example/

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Questions that are primarily begging or attempts to garner sympathy tend to be heavily downvoted. Please don't do it - it is exhausting for volunteers to wade through tales of woe and suffering. Thousands come in every day, and usually they are also badly formatted, unclear, or insufficiently researched.

Comment: `while (foo) { ... }` → `do { ... } while (foo)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you would use a do while over while is you want the code inside the loop to run and then check the condition at the end, if the condition is still true then the code in the do section rans again - in a while loop it happens the other way round.

Try this:

```
do{
        System.out.println("Welcome to Snakes & Ladders");
        System.out.println("1. 2 Player" );
        System.out.println("2. 3 Player");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        menu = scan.nextInt();
    }while (menu < 1 || menu >3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want it to run once regardless of the condition then this will work

```
do{
  //your logic
}while(menu < 1 || menu > 3)
```

if you still want to check the condition for some reason before running (in which case you should be using a while loop)

```
do{
 if(menu > 1 && menu < 3)
   break;
 //your logic
}while(menu < 1 || menu > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

change the keyword

```
while{ to do{  and closing } by }while(condition);
```

observe the changes

```
do{//logic
}while(menu>1 && menu<3);
```

with your code I think there is no sense in making menu<1 && menu>3 raher it should be
menu>1 and menu<3